# adding exit code to processes in xv6

Tags: xv6

I'm trying to add exit status code to processes in XV6.

I've made the following changes:

1) to `sysproc.c`:

```
int
sys_exit(int status)
{
  exit(status);
  return 0;  // not reached
}
```

2) to `defs.h`:

```
...
void            exit(int);
...
```

3) to `proc.h`:

```
struct proc {
  PCB struct elements...
  ...
  int status;                  // added
};
```

4) to `proc.c`:

```
void
exit(int status)
{
  struct proc *curproc = myproc();
  struct proc *p;
  int fd;

  cprintf("exit received: %d\n",status); // for debugging purposes

  curproc->status = status; // added

  ...rest of exit system call...
  }
```

5) to `user.h`:

```
// system calls

...
int exit(int) __attribute__((noreturn));
...
```

Then I wanted to test the added "functionality" by a simple user-space program:

```
int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    exit(3);
}
```

But the following was printed (notice the cprintf call for debugging in `proc.c`):

```
$ exittest
exit received: -2146420507
```

What have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How would I allow parent process to read the exit code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot read the syscall argument like in a 'normal' function, you must use `argint` function (see other syscalls, like `sys_kill`)

So your corrected syscall should be:

```
int
sys_exit(void)
{
  int status;
  if(argint(n, &i) < 0) 
      // not arg:pass 0 to exit
      exit(0);
  exit(status);
  return 0;  // not reached
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot it.